# Javascript Dynamic HREF Creation from XML Element Attribute Values

Tags: javascript, xml, href

I want to use javascript to create dynamic HTML links from the attributes of an xml file.

I have used the following code to successfully write a list of all of the xml element atrributes (file names) I need to an HTML page, but now need to create links instead.

The anchor text of the links should be the XML element attributes (file names) that I had previously used document.write to write to my HTML page. An example of one of these file names from the xml file would be **MyDocument.pdf**

The href link should be made up of a text string prefix "file:///sdcard/portal/" then append the same xml element attributes (file names) to the end which makes up the link. An example of this would be **file:///sdcard/portal/MyDocument.pdf**

I've tried using the document.write method of creating a link but as I also need to use the (x[i].getAttributeNode("name").nodeValue) in the loop to return all of the attributes I'm struggling to make it work.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="myxml-loadxmldoc.js"> 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("MyDocuments.xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{

document.write(x[i].getAttributeNode("name").nodeValue);
document.write("<br>");

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, starting from right above the `for` loop.

```
var path = "file:///sdcard/portal/"; //this will be constant between all iterations
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    var filename = x[i].getAttributeNode("name").nodeValue; //the nodefile is the filename
    document.write("<a href=" + path + filename + ">" + filename + "</a>");
    document.write("<br>");

}
```

That should end up giving you a tag that looks like this in your html:

```
<a href="file:///sdcard/portal/MyDocument.pdf">MyDocument.pdf</a>
```

Comment: Now I'd like to be able to style the links so that the text is larger and not highlighted as a hyperlink. I'd also like to display the links in a table. Further help would be very much appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: These are all somewhat simple things to do in HTML/CSS, and this sort of question really isn't appropriate for a StackOverflow comment. There are plenty of resources online to learn the basics of these concepts, and I'm sure a quick search here on StackOverflow would lead you to answers for each of your questions. But here are a couple links to get you started. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp